# How to get dispatch function reference and action creater as a props inside any connected component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

we get dispatch function ref in our connected component but when we use action creator argument in our connect function then it will not return dispatch function as previously.

**Case 1.** With only first param of connect function.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('this.props',this.props)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        App
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

**Case 2.** Use connect's second parameter also

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setData } from './actions'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log('this.props',this.props)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        App
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return state
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps,{ setData })(App);
```

I expect that in second case,  dispatch function ref should also be listed in props, but its not happend .

Console output :
case 1. dispatch is showing in props https://prnt.sc/ne0fpb

case 2. No dispatch get in props https://prnt.sc/ne0djb

So please help me why i am not getting dispatch function in case 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second `connect` parameter (`mapDispatchToProps`) defaults to `dispatch => ({ dispatch })` function. Default value isn't applied when it's specified.

Since `mapDispatchToProps` is used to provide all needed dispatcher functions as component props, `dispatch` prop isn't needed.

Comment: Thanks i got it , so i can't use action creators and dispatch at same time? @estus

Comment: You can add `dispatch` property to mapDispatchToProps manually. But you don't need to. You already provide all necessary dispatchers with mapDispatchToProps, there's no need to access `dispatch` directly in a component.